# How to output in different jade directory?

Tags: pug

i am new to jade. i am using this command to compile jade

```
jade -w index.jade
```

Now this file is in directory `jade/` but i want the compiled `index.html` in root directory.

Please tell me the command. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `jade -w -o 'yourdir' index.jade`

From the help:

> ~$ jade --help
>
> Usage: jade [options] [dir|file ...]
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> -h, --help             output usage information
> -V, --version          output the version number
> -O, --obj <str|path>   JavaScript options object or JSON file containing it
> -o, --out <dir>        output the compiled html to <dir>
> -p, --path <path>      filename used to resolve includes
> -P, --pretty           compile pretty html output
> -c, --client           compile function for client-side runtime.js
> -n, --name <str>       The name of the compiled template (requires --client)
> -D, --no-debug         compile without debugging (smaller functions)
> -w, --watch            watch files for changes and automatically re-render
> -E, --extension <ext>  specify the output file extension
> -H, --hierarchy        keep directory hierarchy when a directory is specified
> ```

Comment: a google of `jade output different directory` returned surprisingly few results, but the top one was the help with an example (see [here](http://jade-lang.com/command-line/)).

Comment: i can't still get it.

Comment: so you want the file `jade/index.jade` compiled to where? What command did you try?

Comment: Ok i have the jade files in jadeBoy/jade directory. Now  i use jade -w -o */  and want to compile all files from jade directory to root directory that is jadeBoy.. please help

Comment: okay try `jade -w -o ".." */` or `jade -w -o "/path/to/jadeBoy" */`

Comment: or perhaps `jade -w -o '..' index.jade` or `jade -w -o '/path/to/jadeBoy' index.jade`

Comment: not sure how I can help you more. You can try to update your question with the exact layout of your folders, make it clear what you want and post the commands you are trying.